# Accessing session storage object with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Within my apps session storage, I have a `storeDetails` object that I want to access to use with some selection buttons.

in my useEffect hook, I call
`sessionStorage.getItem('tempObjStoreData');` which returns the following data:

```
{
{
    "projectCode": "xxx-xxxx",
    "serviceId": 70377,
    "duration": 30,
    "departmentId": 7,
    "storeDetails": {
        "storeCode": "003",
        "storeName": "Houston",
        "inStore": true,
        "virtual": true
    }
}
```

I want to use the storeDetails (`inStore` or `virtual`) options and use them with the appropriate buttons.

```
  const storeData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tempObjStoreData')) || {};
  let [meetingType, setMeetingType] = useState(storeData);


handleClick = () => {
// logic to determine appt. type
}


          <button onClick={handleClick}
          >
            In Store
          </button>

          <button
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
           Web
          </button>
```

How do I access the storeDetails item within my session storage object and use it in my component?

Comment: you already did it no ? you can't access ```meetingType``` variable inside the ```handleClick``` function ?

Comment: @MarcCharpentier I'm not sure actually how to execute the handleClick function properly.

Comment: can you explain me what is supposed to happen inside ```handleClick``` ? if you press the "in store" button, ```storeDetails.inStore``` value becomes ```true``` ?

Comment: If inStore or virtual  === true, then the button is rendered. Else, the button will be disabled.

Comment: No need for a `useState` here. `<button disabled={!storeData.storeDetails.inStore}>In Store</button>`